# Concatenating arbitrary number of values in lesscss mixin

Tags: css, less

Standard lesscss mixin:

```
.box-shadow(@val) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @val;
    box-shadow: @val;
}
```

However, in pure CSS I'm able to use several box shadows on one element, e.g.

```
#myBox {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
}
```

To ie. create an inset and glow effect. Of course I want to use lesscss to remedy the vendor-prefix curse in this case too, but

```
.box-shadow() {
    -moz-box-shadow: @arguments;
    box-shadow: @arguments;
}

#myBox {
    .box-shadow(inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa);
}
```

will render

```
#myBox {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
}
```

(notice the missing commas after `white`)! Which is syntactically incorrect. Is there any way to trick lesscss into concatenating multiple arguments with `,` instead of ? I thought this should be a more-or-less standard problem, but haven't found any canonical solutions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use an escaped string**

```
#myBox { .box-shadow(~"inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa"); }
```

**Or a javascript escape**

Less 1.2.0 and below:

```
.box-shadow() {
    @shadow: ~`'@{arguments}'.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
       -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
            box-shadow: @shadow;
}
#myBox { .box-shadow(inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa); }
```

Less 1.3.0 and above (requires and uses `...` variadic specifier):

```
.box-shadow(...) {
    @shadow: ~`'@{arguments}'.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
       -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
            box-shadow: @shadow;
}
```

The author's recommended way is an intermediate variable:

```
#myBox {
  @shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  .box-shadow(@shadow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, feeling a bit stupid now... :) But hey, whatever works!

Comment: Note for Less 1.3.0+:

The syntax required to pass variadic arguments uses three dots `...`, so the example above only works for Less 1.2.0 and below.

For those using newer versions of Less, the syntax has change to require:

`.box-shadow(...)`

Comment: @IanHill thanks for the update. I can't find anything on that @ lesscss.org, can you link to documentation?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit hidden and the main page doesn't seem to be as up to date with all the current functionality. The details can be found in the changelog: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, in particular it's the point about "Variadic argument support", which links to the following gist showing the use: https://gist.github.com/1933613

Answer (score 1):

If you escape the argument string as a string literal, it will carry the comma over just as you want:

```
.box-shadow() {
    -moz-box-shadow: @arguments;
    box-shadow: @arguments;
}

#myBox {
    .box-shadow(~"inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa");
}
```

Outputs:

```
#myBox {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px white, 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lessphp (http://leafo.net/lessphp/) for server side compilation (instead of the javascript lesscss compiler from http://lesscss.org) you could bind a php function and use it to change the character used for the concatenation.

**Example lesscss code:**

```
.linear-gradient(@fallback, @deg, @tail...) {
    background-color: @fallback;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@deg, separateByComma(@tail));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@deg, separateByComma(@tail));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@deg, separateByComma(@tail));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@deg, separateByComma(@tail));
}

body {
    .linear-gradient(#FCFCDD, 135deg, #FCFCDD, #FFFFFF 66%, #FCFCDD);
}
```

**Bound php function:**

```
function lesscss_separateByComma($arg) {
    if($arg[0]=='list')
            $arg[1]=',';
        return $arg;
}
```

**And to do the binding and compile the lesscss code:**

```
$less=new lessc();
$less->registerFunction('separateByComma', 'lesscss_separateByComma');
$code=$less->compile($code);
```

**Output:**

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#FCFCDD,#FFFFFF 66%,#FCFCDD);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,#FCFCDD,#FFFFFF 66%,#FCFCDD);
}
```

Tested with lessphp 0.4.0.

Comment: By now all Less compilers (incl. lesphp) support semicolon as mixin parameter delimiter so no `~""` or host language hacks are necessary anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution found [here](http://www.toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/) works with **one** *AND* **multiple** arguments:

```
.box-shadow (@value1,@value2:X,...)
{
    @value: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;

    -webkit-box-shadow: @value;
    -moz-box-shadow: @value;
    -ms-box-shadow: @value;
    -o-box-shadow: @value;
    box-shadow: @value;
}
```