# Can't seem to concatenate two variables in LESS

Tags: css, web, less

I'm trying to combine two variables `@a` and `@b` into a string, with the variables values separated by a comma. This is my attempt:

```
p {
    @a: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    @b: 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    box-shadow: ~"@{a}, @{b}";
}
```

Output:

```
p {box-shadow: [object Object],[object Object]}
```

Expected:

```
p {box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this question & answer might be useful for you :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503088/concatenating-arbitrary-number-of-values-in-lesscss-mixin][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503088/concatenating-arbitrary-number-of-values-in-lesscss-mixin

Comment: Excellent! Not only did that solve my problem, it also gave me a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize from the comments you were directed to an answer that helped. Just to clarify why your original solution did not work, it was because you did not have the variables defined as strings. You needed this (note quotes around your strings):

```
p {
    @a: "inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)";
    @b: "0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6)";
    box-shadow: ~"@{a}, @{b}";
}
```

Comment: You are correct of course. But I don't think this *should* be a solution since CSS (and LESS) is, to my knowledge, meant to be very simplistic, and without the need of explicit data types.

Comment: @Vague--a variable does not need to be defined as an explicit data type in LESS, but they still end up with types. This is evident based on the fact that in the [pattern matching](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions) one can use "basic type checking functions" (one of which being `isstring()` ), of which there are five, so at least five data types are recognized by LESS. Also, that there is [string interpolation and escaping](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation) hints that strings are of type different than say keywords.

Answer (score 0):

**Correction**
Answer updated, per suggestion of @seven-phases-max

The simplest solution works as expected:

```
p {
    @a: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    @b: 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    box-shadow: @a, @b;
}
```

Here is the new demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxeFg

Comment: Merge feature has nothing to do here (see its examples in the docs). Just `box-shadow: @a, @b;` actually works as it's supposed to.