# How do I change the unit of multiple numbers in a Less mixin?

Tags: css, less, mixins, less-mixins

I am trying to create a mixin whereby I can change the unit from px to rem.  For now, I have the following code:

```
@emSize : 16px;
@pxr    : 1 / unit(@emSize, rem);

.padding(@padding) {padding: @padding * @pxr;}

.test {.padding(10px);}
```

This works fine if I only have one number in the mixin, but it does not work if I have multiple numbers.  For instance, this does NOT work:

```
.test {.padding(10px 25px);}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to I could get this to work in Less.

Comment: What happened to the second answer?  It seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating arbitrary number of values in lesscss mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503088/concatenating-arbitrary-number-of-values-in-lesscss-mixin)

Comment: The other answer was removed by the author, since I downvoted because was a only-link answer with a text copied from the blog attached. The blog is that: http://www.toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/ but is out of date. Is better the duplicated entry that I mark before.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

You can use the comma separated values to achieve the same with your minimal code:

```
@emSize : 16px;
@pxr    : 1 / unit(@emSize, rem);

.padding(@verticalpad, @horizontalpad) {
      padding: (@verticalpad * @pxr) (@horizontalpad * @pxr);
}

.test {
      .padding(10px, 25px);
}
```

[**See it working**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%40emSize%20%3A%2016px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40pxr%20%20%20%20%3A%201%20%2F%20unit%28%40emSize%2C%20rem%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.padding%28%40padding%2C%20%40padd%29%20%7Bpadding%3A%20%28%40padding%20*%20%40pxr%29%20%28%40padd%20*%20%40pxr%29%3B%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.test%20%7B.padding%2810px%2C%2025px%29%3B%7D%22%7D)

### Option 2

Did you tried with two functions separated?

```
@emSize : 16px;
@pxr    : 1 / unit(@emSize, rem);

.paddingver(@paddingver) {
       padding-top: @paddingver * @pxr; 
       padding-bottom: @paddingver * @pxr;
}
.paddinghor(@paddinghor) {
       padding-left: @paddinghor * @pxr;
       padding-right: @paddinghor * @pxr;
}

.test {
       .paddingver(10px);
       .paddinghor(25px);
}
```

**[See it working](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%40emSize%20%3A%2016px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40pxr%20%20%20%20%3A%201%20%2F%20unit%28%40emSize%2C%20rem%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.paddingver%28%40paddingver%29%20%7Bpadding-top%3A%20%40paddingver%20*%20%40pxr%3B%20padding-bottom%3A%20%40paddingver%20*%20%40pxr%3B%7D%5Cn%5Ct.paddinghor%28%40paddinghor%29%20%7Bpadding-left%3A%20%40paddinghor%20*%20%40pxr%3B%20padding-right%3A%20%40paddinghor%20*%20%40pxr%3B%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.test%20%7B.paddingver%2810px%29%3B.paddinghor%2825px%29%3B%7D%22%7D)**

Comment: This works fine if I know that I only want 2 numbers.  What I want is the ability to add anywhere from 1 to 4 numbers and have each number converted to rem.  I could make 4 mixins, but I would rather have one mixin with the needed flexibility.

Comment: So see the duplicated entry in the question comments.